# Java retrieve String characters in brackets

Tags: java, string

I have a String in Java that holds data in this format:

```
String x = "xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx (xxx)";
```

How can I set the value of that string to just be the characters in the brackets, without including the brackets? (Note that the character sizes will vary in each instance).

Comment: @RohitJain How, exactly, would you use the split method? It you did, it would be a bit complicated.

Comment: @Bohemian.. Not that complicated.. See my answer below..

Comment: @Bohemian.. However if the input strings changes, I would move towards Regex rather.. But this is quite good for split to work upon..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The one-line solution is to use [`String.replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) and the appropriate regex that captures the whole input (effectively replacing the whole input), but also captures (non-greedily) the part you want as group 1, then puts back just that group:

```
String part = x.replaceAll(".*\\((.*?)\\).*", "$1");
```

FYI, the double back-slashes in the regex String is a single slash in regex, which then escapes the literal brackets in the regex

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx (xxx)";
    String part = x.replaceAll(".*\\((.*)\\).*", "$1");
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

Output:

```
xxx
```

Comment: Thank a lot, this solution seems to be the least accident-prone :)

Comment: @Vash Oh yeah! I don't know why that was there :/  Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3):

A regex will do that, but my regex-fu is weak. The non-regex way is as follows:

```
int firstIndex = x.indexOf("(");
x = x.substring(firstIndex+1, x.length()-1);
```

EDIT: As pointed out in comments, if there are any other parentheses in the data, other than at the end, this will NOT work. You'd need to use the following instead:

```
int firstIndex = x.lastIndexOf("(", x.length()-6);
x = x.substring(firstIndex+1, x.length()-1);
```

EDIT2: Just reread and realised that the close paren is the last character. So there's no need to get the second index.

Comment: If the input is `"abc)def(ghi)"`, your solution will not work. Actually it will throw an exception.

Comment: Yeah. That is the biggest problem, and why the regex method you proposed works better. From the way he phrased the question, I decided that parens only occur at the end. If that's not true, then I'd probably have filled the second param for indexOf to prevent it looking too soon, or use lastIndexOf.

Comment: Since I can't seem to edit my comment, I'll put this here: I've edited my answer to prevent this from happening. Additionally, since the last character is ')', there's no need to calculate a second index; just use length-1, and the substring method will stop before the ')'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.split` method for this kind of extraction..

```
String x = "xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx (xxx)";    
String[] arr = x.split("\\(");

x = arr[1].substring(0, arr[1].indexOf(")")); // To remove the trailing bracket.

System.out.println(x);
```